# Mysql Period Column and Junction Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, mysql-workbench

Our technical adviser in school advised me to start creating master tables of entities before creating the junction tables. He also encouraged me to use composite PRIMARY KEYS instead of COMPOSITE UNIQUE keys for columns.

He told us to really spend most of the time with the database before programming the GUI so I need to make sure that the table design won't cause any problems.

So let's say,

**ONE** class has or belongs to **MANY** schoolyear = TRUE

**ONE** schoolyear has **MANY** classes = TRUE

*Makes me think that having 3 tables,*

**(DESIGN 1):**

**Table 1: Classes**

```
id PK
name
yearlevelId
```

**Junction Table 2: SchoolYearClasses**

```
id PK AI
classId -- FK REFERENCES classes(id)
schoolYearId -- FK REFERENCES schoolyear(id)
```

**Table 3: SchoolYear**

```
id PK AI
schoolYearStart
schoolYearEnd
```

*is better than this*

**(DESIGN 2):**

**Classes**

```
id PK AI
name
yearlevelId  -- FK REFERENCES yearLevel(id)
schoolyearId -- FK REFERENCES schoolyear(id)
```

**SchoolYear**

```
id PK AI
schoolYearStart
schoolYearEnd
```

I need some professional advice here because I'm sure you guys dealt with many systems involving periods. I know the design would affect the transaction inserts ill be creating as well as joins.

Which design is better?
How can I go about inserting records if most of the columns are numerical (id)?

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: The advise on primary keys is not good.  Sometimes, composite primary keys are a good idea, but generally not when the table is being referenced through foreign keys.  In any case, your question is "which is better", and I think that is asking for an opinion.

Comment: I would say it is time to start the GUI

Answer (score 0):

For "junction" tables (to implement many-to-many mappings), I strongly disagree with using an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  You have a perfectly good composite PK, plus you need the pair of ids in reverse order in another `INDEX`.  The end.

[*More on a good schema for M:N*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).  This gives the "whys".

I agree with @Drew --

1. Work on the GUI for a while.
2. Then you will have a feel for what `SELECTs` are needed.
3. Sketch the `SELECTs` based on both of your designs.  It may become obvious that one schema is better.
4. *Then* finalize the schema design.
5. Six months later improve the schema.  (Yes, you will find that the "final" design was not all that good.)